# Blender (2.79b) closes minutes after startup

Tags: error

So a very strange problem. Just installed 2.79b onto my new laptop. When I start up blender the command line comes up as usual, but says "AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead". Blender then seems to run fine, functions normally, but after a minute or two it then suddenly freezes briefly then just closes. Doesn't appear to flash the command line or provide an error message. Not sure what this could be, I just installed the latest gpu drivers for my nvidia gtx1050, and the only drivers I haven't installed for my laptop are the HIDfilter, Hotkey, MEI, SGX, and IRST drivers, which don't sound like they'd interact with blender. It could be antivirus blocking it maybe (bullguard not mcaffee if that makes a difference), but doesn't seem likely as it runs in the first place. Any help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The audio error you can safely ignore.

Comment: Yeah I thought as much :/ It's weird it just closes shortly after startup, irregular time intervals each time

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I installed McAfee antivirus, was previously using windows defender as it turns out (thought I had bullguard free trial, must've had to install that myself) and blender seems to be working fine now, so it's most likely defender was blocking it or something, so if anyone has the same issue, look into your antivirus settings